# Fill grid's datasource with distinct combinations of data

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have one problem about filling a grid.
  
Okey,
  
Imagine we have a grid which prints some data about basketball team.
  
We have four main classes:

```
public class Player
{
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
}

public class Staff
{
    public string StaffName { get; set; }
}

public class Fan
{
    public string FanName { get; set; }
    public List<string> FanFavoriteTeam { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public List<Staff> Staff { get; set; }
    public List<Fan> Fans { get; set; }
}
```

... and of course class which fills the grid

```
public class Result
{
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public string StaffName { get; set; }
    public string FanName { get; set; }
    public string FanFavoriteTeam { get; set; }
}
```

I want to print all possible combinations,for example assume we have this data:
    
Team Name - Golden State Warriors
    
Players - Stephen Curry, Kevin Durant
    
Staff - Steve Kerr, Alvin Gentry, Ron Adams
    
Fans - Duke Allard(Favorite: Celtics,Lakers), Dorian Macy, Lamont Collingwood


Grid should print this info:

```
1st row)Golden State - Stephen Curry - Steve Kerr - Duke Allard - Celtics
2)Golden State - Stephen Curry - Steve Kerr - Duke Allard - Lakers
3)Golden State - Stephen Curry - Steve Kerr - Dorian Macy
4)Golden State - Stephen Curry - Steve Kerr - Lamont Collingwood
5)Golden State - Stephen Curry - Alvin Gentry - Duke Allard - Celtics
6)Golden State - Stephen Curry - Alvin Gentry - Duke Allard - Lakers
7)Golden State - Stephen Curry - Alvin Gentry - Dorian Macy
8)Golden State - Stephen Curry - Alvin Gentry - Lamont Collingwood
9)Golden State - Stephen Curry - Ron Adams - Duke Allard - Celtics
10)Golden State - Stephen Curry - Ron Adams - Duke Allard - Lakers
11)Golden State - Stephen Curry - Ron Adams - Dorian Macy
12)Golden State - Stephen Curry - Ron Adams - Lamont Collingwood
13)Golden State - Kevin Durant - Steve Kerr - Duke Allard - Celtics
14)Golden State - Kevin Durant - Steve Kerr - Duke Allard - Lakers
15)Golden State - Kevin Durant - Steve Kerr - Dorian Macy
16)Golden State - Kevin Durant - Steve Kerr - Lamont Collingwood
17)Golden State - Kevin Durant - Alvin Gentry - Duke Allard - Celtics
18)Golden State - Kevin Durant - Alvin Gentry - Duke Allard - Lakers
19)Golden State - Kevin Durant - Alvin Gentry - Dorian Macy
20)Golden State - Kevin Durant - Alvin Gentry - Lamont Collingwood
21)Golden State - Kevin Durant - Ron Adams - Duke Allard - Celtics
22)Golden State - Kevin Durant - Ron Adams - Duke Allard - Lakers
23)Golden State - Kevin Durant - Ron Adams - Dorian Macy
24)Golden State - Kevin Durant - Ron Adams - Lamont Collingwood
```

P.S. I want to achieve this without chained foreach statements

P.P.S. Sorry for this long description

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to do the looping for you:

```
var result = from t in teams
             from p in players
             from s in staff
             from f in fans
             select new Result {
               TeamName = t.TeamName,
               PlayerName = p.PlayerName,
               StaffName = s.StaffName,
               FanName = f.FanName,
             }
```

This basically does a cross-join of the tables, with no restrictions, so every team is matched with every player, staff, and fan, and we're getting a [Cartesian product](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cartesian_product) of the data.

Comment: Thank you for your response,you really helped me.
But assume we have another field in Fan class, List<string> FanFavouriteTeams(Ex: Celtics,Lakers,Pistons),
    So what's the solution now?